# Textarea scrollHeight not updating preventing auto resize

Tags: javascript, textarea, autoresize

I am kind of stuck on something that seems easy but does not work.

I want to create an auto resize textarea in a modal.
The value of the textarea is added on modal show according to what element activated the modal.

On modal appearance the textarea is not resized and the console reports 0 as scrollHeight.

If I click on the textarea, it is resized.
If i enter or delete text from the textarea, it is resized.

I cannot figure out why it reports scrollHeight 0 when the value is set programmatically.

The resize function is the following.

```
$(document).on("input change focus", "textarea.notesarea", function (e) {
    this.style.height = 'auto';
    console.log(this.scrollHeight+ "-"+ $(this)[0].scrollHeight); 
    if (this.scrollHeight == 0) {
        this.style.height = "calc(2.25rem + 2px)";
    } else {
        this.style.height = 0;
        this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight + 4) + "px";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be to force the code to wait until the modal is first opened before you add "calc(2.25rem + 2px)"; to its height. 
You may use setTimeout(function(){... for example:

```
$(document).on("input change focus", "textarea.notesarea", function (e) {
    this.style.height = 'auto';
    console.log(this.scrollHeight+ "-"+ $(this)[0].scrollHeight); 
    if (this.scrollHeight == 0) {
        that = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
          that.style.height = "calc(2.25rem + 2px)";
        },300);
    } else {
        this.style.height = 0;
        this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight + 4) + "px";
    }
});
```

Comment: I used this approach with some modifications. I set the timeout to 0 and inside the timeout i used the "this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight + 4) + "px";"